# Determine Parameters of gaussian distribution to fit a certain Image-Filter

Tags: image-processing, filters, gaussian, math

I'd like to know what the parameters for the two-dimensional gaussian distributions are, which create this (I think) quite common image-processing filter:
$$
h_\sigma(x,y)=
\left[
\matrix
{
1&2&1\\
2&4&2\\
1&2&1    
}
\right]
$$
The two-dimensional gaussian equation looks like:
$h_\sigma(x,y)= A\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, where $A = \frac{1}{{2\pi}\sigma^2}$, but I think $A$ is not important as it is only a factor, isn't it?

With $\sigma=1$ I get:
$$h_{\sigma=1}(x,y)=
\left[
\matrix
{
h(-1,-1)=0.3679&h(0,-1)=0.6065&h(1,-1)=0.3679\\
h(-1,0)=0.6065&h(0,0)=1.0&h(1,0)=0.6065\\
h(-1,1)=0.3679&h(0,1)=0.6065&h(1,1)=0.3679   
}
\right]
$$
As you see, I think the entries in the filter-matrix correspond to sampling values of the gaussian function from [-1|-1] to [1|1]. I hope that is at least right.

Multiplied $h_{\sigma=1}(x,y)$ with $4$, and then rounded gives me my desired filter, but I don't think that is the correct way, is it?

$$\mbox{round}(4\cdot h_{\sigma=1}(x,y))=
\mbox{round}(4\cdot
\left[
\matrix
{
0.3679&0.6065&0.3679\\
0.6065&1.0&0.6065\\
0.3679&0.6065&0.3679   
}
\right]
)=
$$
$$
h_{\sigma=1}(x,y)=
\mbox{round}(
\left[
\matrix
{
1.4716&2.4260&1.4716\\
2.4260&4.0&2.4260\\
1.4716&2.4260&1.4716
}
\right]
)=
$$
$$
\left[
\matrix
{
1&2&1\\
2&4&2\\
1&2&1    
}
\right]
=h_\sigma(x,y)
$$

There must be a better solution, or mathematical explanation for creating that matrix? I especially dislike the rounding operation, as the values are all close to $.5$ and not to $.0$ which should results in a huge error...

My question in other words: How do I determine the filter from scratch...

Comment: I don't know of any explanation other than "it's kind of like a Gaussian", but that would be even more true if there were a "3" in the center rather than the "4".  I don't think you're going to get a particularly good Gaussian approximation with integers.  Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Gaussian_kernel#The_sampled_Gaussian_kernel or http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/standard-deviation-in-gaussian-blur?rq=1 help?

Comment: Actually, it's not a very good Gaussian.  You would typically want a discrete kernel of size about $\lfloor 6 \sigma + 1 \rfloor$.  So to get away with just 3x3 you need $\sigma < 0.583$.  That gives you a 3x3 kernel with a center about _19x_ greater than the corners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter you referenced is known as a [Binomial filter](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.7611). It is an approximation to a Gaussian, but for smaller filters it's a very crude one. The design is oriented more toward efficiency than accuracy. Rather than sampling a Gaussian directly, the idea behind the approximation is based on the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). In this case, it means that a small moving average filter $[ 1 \space  1 ]$ convolved with itself over and over will become more and more Gaussian. It also happens to yield the rows of [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). The coefficients for larger filters are given by the following formula:

$$
{N \choose k} = \frac{N!}{(N - n)!\space N!}.
$$

For example, for $N = 5$, taking the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of the corresponding row of Pascal's triangle with itself yields

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 6 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 &   4 &   6  &  4  &  1 \\
4 &  16 &  24 &  16  &  4 \\
6 &  24 &  36 &  24  &  6 \\
4 &  16 &  24 &  16  &  4 \\
1 &   4 &   6 &   4  &  1 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The paper I referenced in the first link has the following diagram which shows how the quality of the approximation increases with increasing filter order:
[image]